# How can i use Twitter's search API in nodejs using the fetch API?

Tags: node.js, twitter, fetch

I'm trying to use Twitter's search API in nodejs. I know there are 3rd party libraries for it, but I'm trying to hit the endpoint using `fetch`. Here's my code:

```
const fetch = require('fetch');
const url = `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json`
const options = {
    outputEncoding: 'utf-8',    
    headers: {
        q: 'cbd',
        consumer_key: '****',
        consumer_secret: '****',
        access_token: '****',
        access_token_secret: '****',
    }
}
fetch.fetchUrl(url, options, (err, meta, data) => {
    if(err) console.log(err)
    console.log(data)
})
```

I am confused as to where the keys would go. I have put them in the `options` for the `fetch` call, but I'm not sure if that's where it should be. I get a 'Bad Authentication Data' error here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm the endpoint. I don't think it should ends with `.json`.

Comment: That is the endpoint mentioned [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets). This is the curl request: 
`$ curl --request GET 
 --url 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=from%3Atwitterdev&result_type=mixed&count=2' 
 --header 'authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="consumer-key-for-app", 
 oauth_nonce="generated-nonce", oauth_signature="generated-signature", 
 oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="generated-timestamp", 
 oauth_token="access-token-for-authed-user", oauth_version="1.0"'`

Comment: Okay, let me try.

Comment: I assume options mentioned in the twitter doc is different than what you are sending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use something like following.

```
var fetchUrl = require("fetch").fetchUrl;

fetchUrl('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=from%3Atwitterdev&result_type=mixed&count=2',
       {
         headers: {
            authorization: `Oauth-generated-key`
            }
        }, (err, meta, body) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log('error', err);
                return false;
            }
            console.log('body', body.toString());
            console.log('meta', meta);
           }

       )
```

You can replace `Oauth-generated-key` with

```
OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xvz1evFS4wEEPTGEFPHBog",
oauth_nonce="kYjzVBB8Y0ZFabxSWbWovY3uYSQ2pTgmZeNu2VS4cg",
oauth_signature="tnnArxj06cWHq44gCs1OSKk%2FjLY%3D",
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1569222858",
oauth_token="370773112-GmHxMAgYyLbNEtIKZeRNFsMKPR9EyMZeS9weJAEb",
oauth_version="1.0"
```